# ERC20 Bytecode for Main net

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, myetherwallet, bytecode

I'm trying to Deploy my ERC20 contract in Ethereum main net, but I'm not sure about the bytecode.

I have seen a lot of tutorials but nobody tell something about uploading on main net and bytecode informations.

So i'm using remix , I already used Ropsten network and all work good, now I want to transfer my contract on main net and I'm not sure if I have to use **0xBytecode or only Bytecode generate by Remix**.
On Ropsten I used 0xBytecode, is it the same also on Main network?

And if i want to use **MEW to deploy the contract**, what I have to choose on the top right corner? (myetherwallet.com or etherscan.io)

Comment: You can deploy to the main net in the same way you did on Ropsten using remix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy your token contract to Ethereum main net, there are multiple ways. Concerning the options you mentioned, here are the solutions:

#### Remix with MetaMask

Just as how you deployed to the Ropsten test net, you could set the "Environment" to "Injected Web3" on the "Run" tab. Set your MetaMask account to the "Main Ethereum Network", as shown below. Then you are ready to hit the deploy button and get the contract deployed on the main net.

[image: MetaMask Main Ethereum Network screenshot]

#### MEW with bytecode

1. Go to [the contract section of MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) and select "Deploy Contract".
2. Paste the bytecode of your smart contract in "Byte Code" field. The bytecode could be find by clicking the "Details" button under "Compile" tab in Remix. The code you need to copy is what's inside "object", (with or without 0x)

[image: Screenshot of bytecode object]

3. You could follow the rest of the instruction on MEW to connect to your wallet and eventually deploy your contract.

Comment: Ok, but in the last example, i have to use the normal bytecode or add 0x before it?

Comment: Both are acceptable by MEW. You don't need to prepend 0x.

Comment: And is the same using etherscan.io or myetherwallet.com on top right corner?

Comment: What do you mean by the "top right corner"?

Comment: on MEW, at the top right corner u can choose the network.

Comment: Both etherscan and myetherwallet can select network. It will listen to/interact with different networks based on your choice.

Comment: So the target is the main net and is defined on metamask, so it does not depend on the choice I will make in that field, right?

Comment: The network shown in MetaMask is the decider of the network of deployment. I just made an experiment by selecting "Mainnet" on MEW but "Ropsten" on MetaMask when deploying a contract. No error shown up on either MEW or MetaMask. The contract was deployed eventually on Ropsten because of MetaMask.

Comment: You are welcome ;) Please accept it if you think your problem is solved.